# Using a read-once variable loaded async through react-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm currently playing around with `React`s hooks but currently I'm stuck at mixing different use-cases.

The following scenario is what I am trying to get working. There should be one hook called `useNationsAsync` which is retrieving a list of available nations from the server.
Inside the hook I check if the list has already been loaded/stored to the `localStorage` in order to load it only once.

For the remote-call I use `axios`' `get` call together with the `await` keyword. So this "hook" has to be `async`. I've implemented it the following:

```
export async function getNationsAsync({ }: IUseNationsProps = {}): Promise<NationResource[]> {
    const [storedNations, setStoredNations] = useLocalStorage<NationResource[]>("nations", null);

    if (storedNations == null) {
        const nationsResponse = await Axios.get<NationsGetResponse>("/v1/nations/");
        setStoredNations(nationsResponse.data.nations);
    }

    return storedNations;
}
```

The `useLocalStorage`-hook is the one which can be found [here](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) (only typed for use with `TypeScript`).

In my final `FunctionalComponent` I only want to read the nations once so I thought using the `useEffect` hook with an empty array would be the place to be (as this is mainly the same as `componentDidMount`).
However, on runtime I get the following error on the first line of my `getNationsAsync`-hook:

> Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call.

The usage in my `FunctionalComponent` is:

```
const [nations, setNations] = React.useState<NationResource[]>([]);

const fetchNations = async () => {
    const loadedNations = await getNationsAsync();
    setNations(loadedNations);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchNations();
}, []);
```

I know that the issue is for calling `useHook` inside the method passed to `useEffect` which is forbidden. 
The problem is, that I don't get the right concept on how to use the nations at a central point (a hook sharing the result, not the logic) but only load them once in the components which do need nations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you are creating manages the state of nations and returns it.
Instead of `useState` you are using `useLocalStorage` which, as far as I could read from the source, uses as initial state a `localStorage` value or the given value (`null` in your case) if there is no local one.

```
export const useNations = ():
    | NationResource[]
    | null => {
    const [storedNations, setStoredNations] = useLocalStorage<
        NationResource[] | null
    >("nations", null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // If storedNations has a value don't continue.
        if (storedNations) {
            return;
        }

        const fetch = async () => {
            // Check the types here, Im not sure what NationsGetResponse has.
            const nationsResponse = await Axios.get<NationsGetResponse>(
                "/v1/nations/"
            );

            setStoredNations(nationsResponse.data.nations);
        };

        fetch();
    }, []);

    return storedNations;
};
```

Then you can use this hook in any component:

```
export const MyComponent: React.ComponentType<Props> = props => {
    const nations = useNations();

    return // etc.
};
```

Comment: And then I should use it like `const nations = React.useMemo(()=> useNations(), []);`?

Comment: @KingKerosin see the edit, I included an example. There is no need to memoize, if Im correct, the value is held in a state which updates only once (when it fetches, if it is necessary). Let me know if its not clear.

Comment: Just to be clear - as I am still struggeling with getting the new concepts right. If I would not know that the `useLocalStorage` hook internally uses `useState` would I rather use `useMemo(...)` or `useRef<NationResource[]>(...).current` in my final component?

Comment: @KingKerosin `useMemo` memoizes a value that is heavy on calculation so that it does not need to do it on every render, only when one of its dependencies change. `useRef` is similar to an external variable, its cheaper than a state and it doesn't trigger a render when it changes. For your case you don't need any of them. Taking this logic out to a hook is just for convenience, you could simply add the hook code directly in the component, it'd be the same. About `useLocalStorage`, well, I would rather simply check `localStorage` in the initial value of `useState`. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: @KingKerosin Just checked the code again. What it does is check if there is an initial `localStorage` value and if so set it as initial. It also saves/updates to `localStorage` any new value assigned. If you need both functionalities then its convenient to use it. Think of the hook as if you simply copied its code inside your component, you'd have a `state`, `const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState...`  and a function which uses `setStoredValue` with some extra functionality. I don't think there is any need to memoize in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add async to custom hooks. I think this is what you're looking for.

```
export function getNations(props) {
    const [storedNations, setStoredNations] = useLocalStorage("nations",[]);

    async function getNations() {
      const nationsResponse = await Axios.get("/v1/nations/");
      setStoredNations(nationsResponse.data.nations);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      if (storedNations.length === 0) {
        getNations()
      }
    }, [])
    return storedNations;
}
```

You can call it like this

```
  function App() {
     const nations = getNations()
     return (
       // jsx here
     )
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add an example on how this would be used/invoked on a functional component (as `async` calls are somewhat "difficult" to be used in a non-async function ;) )?

Comment: Not sure about the complete edit... But to me it seems to be the same as the first answer now. Correct me if I am wrong or missing the point here

Comment: totally same as first answer